# Objective-C: typedef'd a block, used it in a method declaration. How do I implement this?

Tags: objective-c, block

Just trying to get a handle on blocks.  I get the concept.  They're like function pointers, but they're actually objects; you can declare a block variable and assign it a block value; call it like a function; they get "frozen in time," for lack of a term, when they get executed, etc.  I've created a few blocks and run them successfully, in a few different formats, but when it comes to using them in a method--either with a typedef or without--I'm having a lot of trouble.  For example, here's an object interface I created, just to get a handle on the syntax.  I have almost no idea how to implement it.

```
// AnObject.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// The idea with the block and the method below is for the block to take
// an int, multiply it by 3, and return a "tripled" int.  The method
// will then repeat: this process however many times the user wants via
// the howManyTimes parameter and return that value in the form of an int.

typedef int (^triple)(int);

@interface AnObject : NSObject
{
    int num;
}

-(int)repeat:(int)howManyTimes withBlock:(triple)someBlock;

@end
```

Here's what I have for an implementation, so far:

```
#import "AnObject.h"

@implementation AnObject

@synthesize num;

-(int)repeat:(int)howManyTimes withBlock:(triple)someBlock {
    for (int i = 0; i <= howManyTimes; i++) {
        // What the heck am I supposed to put here?  I'm baffled by the
        // syntax over and over again.
    }
}

@end
```

I know I'm not addressing the instance variable yet.  Again, this is a rough draft, just trying to get a handle on how blocks work.  Am I even declaring this method right?  I'm reading Big Nerd Ranch's Objective-C Programming, Mike Clark's article on blocks from Pragmatic Studio, and several SO threads.  Can't find anything relevant.  Thanks.

EDIT:  XCode 4.3.2, if it matters.

FURTHER EDIT:  Ok.  Using BJ's (slightly modified) example, I think I've come up with a really complicated way of multiplying 5 by 3.  :)

```
// BJ's implementation:

-(int)repeat:(int)howManyTimes withBlock:(Triple)someBlock {

    int blockReturnValue;

    for (int i = 0; i <= howManyTimes; i++) {
        blockReturnValue = someBlock(i);
    }
    return blockReturnValue;
}
```

Main:

```
...
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        AnObject *obj = [[AnObject alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"%d", [obj repeat: 5 withBlock: ^ (int number) {
            return number * 3;
        }]);

    }
    return 0;
...
```

And the output is:

```
15
```

Now, it's kicking back 15, because the block I defined as an argument is run only once, right?  It multiplies "number," which is 5 in this case, by 3 and freezes that answer, right?  I'm sure I just created a completely useless method, and I don't yet understand how to utilize the benefits/features of a block.  Am I correct?

/***************************************  UPDATE  ***************************************/

UPDATE:  I understand what you're saying, CRD.  Just a correction though, for any new programmers who might be reading this, getting a different output and going, "Que?"  Your for loop should be either:

```
for (int i = 0; i < howManyTimes; i++)
            value = someBlock(value);
```

...or...

```
(i = 1; i <= howManyTimes; i++)
```

...to get the answer 243.

And, yes, this is exactly what I was initially trying to do with this code.  At least that's what I thought was supposed to be happening.  Turns out the author's intent wasn't to triple a number, store that value, triple the stored value, store that...etc., but rather just to print x * 3 for numbers 1-5 (3, 6, 9, 12, 15).

Here is the finished product.  I just typedef'd a block that takes an int and returns an int, called Tripler.  I also changed the name of the argument from "someBlock" to "triple" to more clearly indicate the intended use of the block.  I think those are the only changes to the code.

```
/********************  interface  ********************/


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef int (^Tripler)(int);

@interface AnObject : NSObject

-(void)iterateFromOneTo:(int)number withBlock:(Tripler)triple;

@end

/********************  implementation  ********************/


#import "AnObject.h"

@implementation AnObject

-(void)iterateFromOneTo:(int)number withBlock:(Tripler)triple {
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%d", triple(i));
    }
}

@end

/********************  main.m  ********************/


#import "AnObject.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        AnObject *obj = [[AnObject alloc] init];

        [obj iterateFromOneTo:5 withBlock:^(int number) {
            return number * 3;
        }];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can probably imagine, the resulting output is:

```
2012-05-05 17:10:13.418 Untitled 2[71735:707] 3
2012-05-05 17:10:13.445 Untitled 2[71735:707] 6
2012-05-05 17:10:13.446 Untitled 2[71735:707] 9
2012-05-05 17:10:13.446 Untitled 2[71735:707] 12
2012-05-05 17:10:13.447 Untitled 2[71735:707] 15
```

I was making it a lot more complicated than it needed to be.  Sorry for explaining it so poorly in the OP.  Thanks for your help!  /thread?  :)

Comment: Go through this Block Explanation... http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/852_Introduction_to_Objective_C_Blocks.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just call the block like a regular C function.

```
-(int)repeat:(int)howManyTimes withBlock:(triple)someBlock {
    for (int i = 0; i <= howManyTimes; i++) {
        int blockReturnValue = someBlock(i);
        // do something with blockReturnValue
    }
}
```

**Update after your "further edit"**

No, the block you passed in as an argument is run five times, each pass through the for loop.

- The first time, it invokes the block with `1` as the argument, and gets back `3`. It stores that in `blockReturnValue`, then goes on to the next iteration of the loop.
- The second time, it invokes the block with `2` as the argument, and gets back `6`. It stores that in `blockReturnValue`, **completely overwriting the value we stored there in the previous pass**.
- The third time, it inbokes the block with `3` as the argument, and gets back `9`. Again, it overwrites the value in `blockReturnValue`.
- The fourth time, we store `12` in `blockReturnValue`.
- The fifth time, we store `15` in `blockReturnValue`.

Then we exit the for loop, and return 15. So yes, you're correct that you've made a pointless method to multiply by 3. But you're doing it in a way that also does a bunch of useless calculations.

Comment: All right.  Maybe it's simpler than I'm making it out to be.  Working on that now.

Comment: Ok.  Please see "FURTHER EDIT:"  Thanks for the help, BJ.

Comment: I think I have a low programming IQ, unfortunately.  :P  I get the gist of what's happening.  It should be clearer, but it's just the syntax that's giving me fits, I guess.  That's what's keeping me from following what's really going on.  I'm just gonna ingest as much about blocks as I can until I finally see how they work and when to properly use 'em.  Thanks so much for your help and patience.

Answer (score 8):

From reading your question I understood, or maybe misunderstood, that your intention was to produce the result of applying your block *n* times; e.g. if you applied a tripling function twice you'd get the original value multiplied by nine.

Just in case it helps, here is the code to do that:

```
@interface AnObject

typedef int (^monadic)(int); // an function which takes an int and return an int

- (int) repeat:(int)howManyTimes for:(int)value withBlock:(monadic)someBlock;

@end

@implementation AnObject

- (int) repeat:(int)howManyTimes for:(int)value withBlock:(monadic)someBlock
{
   for (int i = 0; i < howManyTimes; i++)
      value = someBlock(value);

   return value;
}

@end
```

Now call this with:

```
AnObject *myObject = [AnObject new];

int z = [myObject repeat:5  
                     for:1 
               withBlock: ^(int number)
                          {
                             return number * 3;
                          }
        ];
```

and `z` will have the value `243`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, CRD.  Appreciate you takin' the time.  See the "UPDATE" above.

Comment: @baptzmoffire - correct, oops :-( fixed the typo, now it produces 243!

Answer (score 1):

```
@import Foundation;

typedef int(^MyBlockType)(int);

@implementation NSObject(extra)
+ (int)invokeBlock:(MyBlockType)block withArgument:(int)arg
{
    return block(arg);
}
@end;

int main() {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"executeBlock(3) returns %d",
              [NSObject invokeBlock:^(int param) { return param * param; } withArgument:3]);
    } return 0;
}
```